# diesel.rs and rocket.rs: don't understand why it wants a databases table

Tags: rust, rust-diesel, rust-rocket

I'm new to Rust, and I'm having an issue I can't wrap my head around.

My `Cargo.toml` looks like this:

```
[dependencies]
rocket = "0.4.6"
rocket_codegen = "0.4.6"
serde = "1.0"
serde_derive = "1.0"
serde_json = "1.0"

[dependencies.diesel]
version = "1.0.0"
default-features = false
features = ["sqlite"]

[dependencies.rocket_contrib]
version = "0.4.6"
default-features = false
features = ["diesel_sqlite_pool"]

[global.databases.urls_db]
url = "urls.sqlite"
```

I have the connection like this on the `main.rs`:

```rust
use rocket_contrib::databases::diesel;

#[database("urls_db")]
struct UrlsDbConn(diesel::SqliteConnection);
```

The only table I have is one called `urls`, as per `schema.rs`:

```rust
table! {
    urls (id) {
        id -> Text,
        uri -> Text,
    }
}
```

But when I try to `cargo run` it I get:

```rust
Error: Database configuration failure: 'urls_db'
    => Error: A table named `databases` was not found for this configuration
```

Any idea why?

The only place I have a `databases` (plural) string is on the `Cargo.toml` (`global.databases.urls_db`), which is how rocket.rs instructs to set it up...

---

EDIT: fixed typo;
EDIT2: the database itself seems fine:

```
main: /Users/carlos/Developer/caarlos0/beckerly/beckerly/urls.sqlite
sqlite> .tables
__diesel_schema_migrations  urls
sqlite> select * from urls;
sqlite> insert into urls(id, uri) values ('g', 'https://google.com');
sqlite> select * from urls;
g|https://google.com
sqlite>
```

Comment: Did you check if database name my_db exists in sqlite

Comment: Could it be something needed by Sqlite?

Comment: I think the db should be fine, it ran the migrations just fine (`create table`)...

Comment: I think the error is referring to "table", as in a section of TOML configuration. Besides, where did the `my_db` string come from? Could it be the discrepancy between names here: `urls_db` and `my_db`?

Comment: Fixed the `my_db` thing, initially I was hiding the db name in the question and later gave up but forgot to change this part.

Comment: @justinas Yeah, it also seems to me that it is complaining about something in the toml file, not sure what it is expecting though...

Comment: I am not too knowledgeable with Rocket, but shouldn't you use `Rocket.toml` rather than `Cargo.toml` for the database configuration?

Comment: @justinas exactly, just found that out too (after hours debugging).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The database config should be in a `Rocket.toml` file:

```
[global.databases]
urls_db = { url = "urls.sqlite" }
```

The documentation clearly says so:

> Then, in Rocket.toml or the equivalent via environment variables, configure the URL for the database in the databases table: